# List of conlangs whose goal is to minimize ambiguity

Tags: ambiguity, list-of-languages, design-goals

Which conlangs have a primary goals of avoiding ambiguity?

I know Lojban had that as a goal (and is in fact syntactically unambiguous), but are there others?

Answer (score 6):

Here are the top five best-known (see footnote 1).

- Lojban at [lojban.org](https://mw.lojban.org/papri) is the better-known successor of Loglan.
- Loglan at [loglan.org](http://loglan.org) is based on formal logic and is to some extent not unlike a transcription of formal logic (see footnote 2).
- Ithkuil at [ithkuil.net](http://ithkuil.net) is like the two above but is as compact as possible, allowing to read, write, say, and hear complex thoughts and ideas in a matter of seconds.
- Ceqli at http://ceqli.pbworks.com/w/page/5455970/FrontPage is originally inspired by Loglan but later a bit more naturalist
- CycL at http://www.cyc.com/documentation/ontologists-handbook/cyc-basics/syntax-cycl/ is a lot like a programming language intended mainly for neural networks. It's more suitable for expressing knowledge than for communication.

All these have Wikipedia articles under their name, except Ceqli (available on [Dutch Wikipedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceqli)) to which you can go via the link given.

---

Footnotes: 1) These languages (except Lojban and possibly Ithkuil) don't actively disambiguate *phonemic* ambiguity. That's the difference between 'an app' and 'a nap'. It resulted in English *a nickname*, from *an ekename*.
2) An example of formal logic, using prerequisite axioms `[PERSON(a) 'A is a person', HAVE_ALIENABLE(a, b) 'A has B alienably', HEAD(a) 'A is a head']`, is `∀ x: PERSON(x) → (∃ y: HAVE_ALIENABLE(x, HEAD(y)))` ('Everyone has a head', 'For every X, if X is a person, there exists some Y which X has alienably and which is a head').

Comment: "1) These languages (except Ithkuil, AFAIK) don't actively disambiguate phonemic ambiguity." Lojban does explicitly try to; hence the use of "." as a phoneme, for proper names, which are going to violate the built-in phonotactics most readily.